# Countability and surjective, injective mappings

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I am studying famous book "Introduction to Real analysis" by "Robert G. Bartle & Donald R. Sherbert".

I saw a theorem which states that:

The following three statements are equivalent:

a) $S$ is countable set

b) There exists surjection of $N$ onto $S$

c) There exists injection of $S$ into $N$.

I want to know if theorem holds true? Is it true even if we take $S  = ∅$ where $∅$ is the empty set?

If yes, please explain me why it is true?

If not then, do b) & c) imply a), but not conversely?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that we must assert $S \neq \emptyset$. In fact, for any set $A \neq \emptyset$, there exists no function from $A$ to $\emptyset$. This is because by the definition of a function, for each $x \in A$ there would be a $y \in \emptyset$ such that $(x, y) \in f$. This is impossible, since $\emptyset$ contains no elements.